# How to prevent invalid input

Tags: javascript, html, validation

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#input');

el.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.target.willValidate && !e.target.validity.valid) {
    // invalid
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};

el.oninput = function(e) {
  result.innerHTML = e.target.value;
};
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" id="input">
<span id="result"></span>
```

So if I type or paste an invalid value eg `11`, the `result` doesn't update. How do I ensure the input just ignores invalid input and/or reverts to the last valid value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a reference to the last valid value, and insert it when something invalid is put in:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#input');

let lastVal;
el.oninput = function(e) {
  if (this.willValidate && !this.validity.valid) {
    this.value = lastVal;
  } else {
    lastVal = el.value;
    result.innerHTML = e.target.value;
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" id="input">
<span id="result"></span>
```

It could also be done by intercepting all methods which result in input changes, figuring out what the new value would be by checking the selection index and what the newly added values would be (and possibly deleting old sections of text, if they were selected), and then using `preventDefault` to prevent the invalid text from being inputted at all, but that would be a whole lot more complicated for basically the same result.

An example snippet in Vue using the same method:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    val: '',
    oldVal: ''
  },
  watch: {
    val(newVal) {
      if (!(newVal >= 1 && newVal <= 10)) {
        this.val = this.oldVal;
      } else {
        this.oldVal = newVal;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="val">
  <span>{{ val }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm probably after the 'complicated' route you mention cause this is a simplied example in a large Vue app, so I can't just set a `lastVal` :( I tried preventDefault in `keyUp` event but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Using `keyup` event you mean? It doesn't stop the value from being saved. I've updated my example.

Comment: I'd think that you'd be able to do the same sort of thing in Vue - on input, if the value isn't valid, revert to the last valid input, is there something about Vue that prevents that from being an option?

Comment: I made a snippet that appears to work, but like I said, it blinks. Never used Vue before in my life, there might be a better way

Comment: Did you try the snippet?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround using `onpaste` event. But it takes the `min` and `max` value and then try to validate against the value manually. But it will prevent the input value from being changed if wrong values is pasted.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#input');


el.onpaste = function(e){
  var pastedVal = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  if(pastedVal < parseInt(el.getAttribute("min")) || pastedVal > parseInt(el.getAttribute("max"))){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" id="input">
<span id="result"></span>
```